# Extending an entity framework 6 class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, partial-classes

I have the class generated by Entity Framework called Person.cs which is in namespace Project.Model.

I have then put a new folder in the project called Extensions, added Person.cs inside there and set the namespace for this file to Project.Model.

After doing this, I get the error:

> Type 'Project.Model.Person' already defines a member called 'Person'
>   with the same parameter types.

What am I doing wrong? I need to extend EF Person.cs to have other properties.

Here is my code for the extended Person.cs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project.Model
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove default constructor from `Person` class:

```
public partial class Person
{
    // add properties here
}
```

Your partial class is a part of the same class, so as with any other classes definitions - no member can be defined twice, including constructor. If you'll go to `Person` class generated by EF, you will see that it already has default constructor (EF uses it for navigation properties initialization).

Comment: Is this a good place to put those extensions though? Or should I instead create domain models in the business layer and use automapper to map between them?